# completion:nil on presentModalViewController

Tags: ios6, deprecated

When I set

```
[self presentModalViewController:Facebookcontroller animated:YES];
```

to

```
[self presentViewController:Facebookcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

to erase the presentModalViewController:animated is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0

pops another warning:

Instance method '-presentModalViewController:animated:completion:' not found (return type defaults yo 'id')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Are you sure `self` is a UIViewController in this context. You can call this code only from another UIViewController.
2. Make sure you initialize the Facebookcontroller class first, you cannot pass just the class. `Facebookcontroller *facebookController = Facebookcontroller alloc] init];`

For iOS 6 use:

```
[self presentViewController:Facebookcontroller animated:YES completion:^{
    //Do whatever you want to do when the controller 'Facebookcontroller' is presented.
}];
```

or

```
[self presentViewController:Facebookcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You can find the reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW75).

Comment: Yes ;). Anyway it worked for me ! What about the dismissModalViewControllerAnimated... the same?

Comment: Looks okay, you may want to use "facebookController" instead of "FacebookController". Check out:  http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php

Comment: yes use the same for dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: